# whether a string has digits or special characters and throw an exception

Tags: java

in java,
is it possible to check a string has special characters or letters on it and if so throw an exception?

something like this but using try/catch

```
/** Get and Checks if the ssn is valid or not **/
    private String getSSN(){
        String tempSSN;
        tempSSN = scan.nextLine();
        if(tempSSN.matches("^.*[^a-zA-Z ]{9}.*$") == false){
            System.out.print("enter a valid SSN without spaces or dashes.");
            tempSSN= scan.nextLine();
        }
        return tempSSN;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do it without exception handling, there is no obvious reason for why you would use a `try-catch` block. But if you want to throw an exception, it's not a must to use a try-catch block. You can use `throw`.

```
    if(something) {
        throw new SomeAppropriateException("Something is wrong");
    }
```

You can use a `catch` block if you want to catch an exception and log any error or message and continue the execution. Or you catch an exception when you want to throw other meaningful exception.

Answer (score 0):

I would import the characters into an array of characters then use a loop to check each character for the character types that you want to throw the exception for.

Some sudo code below:

```
private String getSSN(){
    String tempSSN = scan.nextLine();

    try {
    char a[] = tempSSN.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        if(a[i] != ^numbers 0 - 9^) {      //sudo code here. I assume you want numbers only.
           throw new exceptionHere("error message");   // use this to aviod using a catch. Rest of code in block will not run if exception is thrown.
    }

    catch (exceptionHere) {      // runs if exception found in try block
        System.out.print("enter a valid SSN without spaces or dashes.");
        tempSSN= scan.nextLine();
    }
    return tempSSN;
}
```

I would also consider running an if on the array not being 9 characters in length. I assume you are trying to capture ssn's which are always 9 characters.

```
if (a.length != 9) {
   throw ....
}
```

You can do this without the try/catch. And the above will break if they enter an invalid ssn a second time.

```
    private String getSSN(){
    String tempSSN = scan.nextLine();

    char a[] = tempSSN.toCharArray();
    boolean marker;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        if(a[i] != ^numbers 0 - 9^) {      //sudo code here. I assume you want numbers only.
           boolean marker = false;
    }

    while (marker == false) {
        System.out.print("enter a valid SSN without spaces or dashes.");
        tempSSN = scan.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
              if(a[i] != ^numbers 0 - 9^) {      //sudo code here. I assume you want numbers only.
                  marker = false;
              else 
                  marker = true;
    }
    }
    return tempSSN;
}
```

You can optionally use the contains method in some way I am sure.

```
boolean marker = tempSSN.contains(i.toString());  // put this in the for loop and loop so long as i < 10; this will go 0 - 9 and check them all.
```